# I have Excel version 2019, PowerView doesn't work. How can If ix it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Excel version 2019 (version 16.0.12026.20264). It's on Windows 10.

I added [PowerView](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-98268d31-97e2-42aa-a52b-a68cf460472e) and activated Solver.

I have activated SilverLight using the files and guide from [this link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Registry-keys-to-reenable-7cd9f723)

When I use PowerView, I only get a blank picture like in [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-powerview-error-image/28564661-ebc1-426c-8f56-e6bb96d14d4a)

Also it doesn't work at all.

What can be the error? How can I fix this?

Comment: Silverlight link is for office 2016, it may not work for 2019.

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: maybe download power BI

Comment: Power View is deprecated. It is only in Excel for backwards compatibility. Don't expect to be able to use it like in Excel 2013. It's basically dead.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of Power View is now accessible from the Power BI Desktop.

All the functionality is still available (and supported in Excel 2016/2019) but the ribbon command has been removed.

The command button is still available and can be added manually by customising the ribbon.

[image]

I have a retail version of Office 2019(Version 1909 Build 12026.20320) installed on my computer. After I enable Power View add-in in Excel options, add the button to ribbon and unblock Silverlight via modify registry key, I can reproduce the issue you are encountering:

[image]

There is one thing you are missing: you don't have Silverlight installed. Please download and install it from the page [Get Microsoft Silverlight](https://mssilverlight.azurewebsites.net/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default) .

When you finish installing Microsoft Silverlight, you can click the button to insert a new Power View properly:

[image]

I use Office Professional Plus 2019 (Volume licensing, Version 1808 Build 10351.20054) to test and get the same result.

Hope it helps.